# Big-IP F5 irule get uri and store in variable

Tags: f5, irule

There is my irule config as below :

```
when HTTP_REQUEST {
switch [HTTP::query] {
    "*NetTest0*" {
         HTTP::respond 200 content "NetTest0()"
    }
    "*NetTest1*" {
         HTTP::respond 200 content "NetTest1()"
    }
    "*NetTest2*" {
         HTTP::respond 200 content "NetTest2()"
    }
    "*NetTest3*" {
         HTTP::respond 200 content "NetTest3()"
    }
}}
```

Is there any method can get uri as a variable, and replace NetTest0 to NetTest0()?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [HTTP::uri](https://clouddocs.f5.com/api/irules/HTTP__uri.html) command to get and set the URI. Depending on the complexity of your replacements, you can use [string map](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/string+map) (preferred for performance reasons) or [regsub](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/regsub) (avoid if possible, but useful if you need it.)

Here are a couple examples of the string map that should help you get started:

- https://community.f5.com/t5/technical-forum/variable-in-a-string-map/td-p/263863
- https://community.f5.com/t5/technical-forum/string-map-with-variables-including-quotes/td-p/252969

We recently [launched a new platform and engaging on DevCentral](https://community.f5.com/) is far easier than before, feel free to join us there for future F5-related questions!